# How can I print a list by user input?

Tags: python, user-input

If I have several lists, for example:

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[1,4,6]
C=[11,4,100]
x=input("which list do you want to print?")
print(x)
```

If I should choose A, I want the result to be: 1,2,3
but what I have instead just shows "A".

How do I solve this?

Comment: Ultimate rooky, just programming for the first day..

Comment: Much easier with an array (or list) of lists than separate variables, if you can do that. Else you can at least use something like if x == 'A' then print(A) else if x == 'B' then print5b) and so on. + add a tag for a specific programming language (pytho? C?) if you want a real syntax to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you say this is your first day programming, this answer will unfortunately not adequately explain things to you, but you can look up what is used below.  There are many good Python books, but I do not have a specific one to recommend for someone just beginning.  (I am guessing that you are using Python based on your syntax and functions.)

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 4, 6]
C = [11, 4, 100]
x = input("which list do you want to print?")
print("You chose: " + x)
choices = {"A": A, "B": B, "C": C}
print(choices.get(x, "unknown choice!"))
```

The curly-brace syntax for the "choices" variable is called a dict, which is short for dictionary.

Comment: I am using books from O'reilly, but just starting is easier. For programming using Pycharm. Thx.

Comment: Thx. Its working.